# How to add a cumulative column based on a value divided by size of each group?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

How do I create the goal column so that it takes the "value", divides it by the # of times a unique value of "name" appears.

- So for B we start at 1.2 and it is 1.2/2 = 0.6
- For the next value of B we can do 0.6+0.6 (only 2 B's in name column) to get 1.2
- For C the first instance is 0.6/3 = 0.2 and for each date as we get to the end date for C we add 0.2 to get 0.6 finally.

Here's a reproducible example:

```
name <- c("A","B","B","C","C","C")
date <- c('2024-01-01', '2024-01-01', '2024-02-01', '2024-01-01','2024-02-01','2024-03-01')
value<- c("1.0","1.2","1.2","0.6","0.6","0.6")
count <- c("1","1","2","1","2","3")
df <- data.frame(name,date,value,count)

  name       date  value count 
   A   2024-01-01  1.0     1  
   B   2024-01-01  1.2     1  
   B   2024-02-01  1.2     2  
   C   2024-01-01  0.6     1  
   C   2024-02-01  0.6     2  
   C   2024-03-01  0.6     3
```

This is my desired output:

```
goal <- c("1.0","0.6","1.2","0.2","0.4","0.6")
finaldf <- data.frame(name,date,value,count,goal)

  name       date  value count goal
   A   2024-01-01  1.0     1  1.0
   B   2024-01-01  1.2     1  0.6
   B   2024-02-01  1.2     2  1.2
   C   2024-01-01  0.6     1  0.2
   C   2024-02-01  0.6     2  0.4
   C   2024-03-01  0.6     3  0.6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(goal = cumsum(as.numeric(value) / n()), .by = name)

#>   name       date value count goal
#> 1    A 2024-01-01   1.0     1  1.0
#> 2    B 2024-01-01   1.2     1  0.6
#> 3    B 2024-02-01   1.2     2  1.2
#> 4    C 2024-01-01   0.6     1  0.2
#> 5    C 2024-02-01   0.6     2  0.4
#> 6    C 2024-03-01   0.6     3  0.6
```

Comment: I don't get the same goal column when I run that code, I get 0.1666667, 0.366..., 0.566.. and so on until 0.86 and thanks for cleaning up the post

Comment: @chriswang123456 what if instead of using `.by` you added `group_by(name) >%>` before `mutate(...)`. I suspect you have an older version of dplyr installed.